# Site Address (URL) - causing error 404

Tags: errors, 404-error

I have the following situation which I tried to solve by using the website and forum but unfortunately no success so far.

I am working on a new site (old still-now online) but when changing the Site Address (URL), i receive a error 404 when trying to accees the site www.gas-spring.com. [image]

When changing the permalink settings and saving them there is no change and I still receive the error 404. When I change the Site Address (URL) back to wordpress URL everything is working fine. I stopped plugins and clearing cache etc.. but nothing seems to work.

The .htaccess is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I really would like to receive some help in resolving this. I'm a beginner with Wordpress so maybe I have overlooked something.

I use filezilla to upload the site and the files are stored in - /home/www/public_html/wordpress

If i check the following link, https://www.gas-spring.com/wordpress/ , I can see some of the website loading but still with errors.

Filezilla / folder : [image]

Please inform me if you require any more info. 
Thanks in advace,
Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed your website in public_html/wordpress so you need to move it up a directory in FTP or change your URL in the dashboard to gas-springs.com/wordpress.

The JSON error is because your Wordpress URL is HTTP and the Site URL is HTTPS.

Comment: Thanks TomC, so place the complete folder > /home/www/wordpress ? And not under public-html ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Unless you wanted to have /wordpress/ in the URL.

Comment: Also, generally speaking, you want the Wordpress address URL and Site URL the same. 
And once you change it, you'll need to use gas-spring.com/wp-admin to access the admin dashboard.

Comment: Thanks TomC, apologies for not replying sooner.

I have placed the entire folder to home/www/wordpress and changed siteurl and home to https://www.gas-spring.com. Unfortunately I still see no website. If i check the site in test ( http://w7qg742b8.homepage.t-online.de/wordpress/ ) it workes fines.

I tried the .htaccess with RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L] and RewriteRule ./index.php [L].

Is there something I am missing ? Thanks again for the replies.

Comment: You were supposed to move the files out of the 'home/www/public_html/wordpress' directory and into the 'home/www/public_html' directory. You don't need to modify the .htaccess files.

Comment: Sorry misunderstanding.

I have now moved all files and folders from wordpress to public.html. The homepage is loading but links are broken or not linked correctly. In test it is working fine. Any idea why this is not working ?

Comment: Edit - I changed permalinks and am manually updating some links. I appears to be working. Thanks a million for the help and info. If I require any more info I will be sure to contact you all on this form.

Comment: Thanks - please mark my answer as correct if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change site address in database direct. You can use below link to generate sql query to change your old url to new url.
https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/full/nzEjI

and try below .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have changed and updated the .htaccess file but, no success and the error 404 remains. 

What do you mean with ,"You can also change site address in database direct"? Where do I change this ? I can accees the PhP Myadmin.

Comment: have you change siteurl and wordpress url?

Comment: Yes, i have now changed the siteurl and wordpress url both to https://www.gas-spring.com but still the errors remains. I

Comment: Your folder structure is in wordpress directory?

Comment: My folders are uploaded to - /home/www/public_html/wordpress - See original post for filezilla file.

Comment: RewriteRule . wordpress/index.php [L], change this line in .htaccess and try.

Comment: Changed, but without success. Do I need to change something in the siteurl or config.php ?

Comment: Have you point your domain to wordpress folder or some other folder, may be you point wrong folder.

Comment: If I change the siteur and home in Php Myadmin to https://www.gas-spring.com/wordpress/ the site loads but other pages do not load correctly or links are broken.

Comment: Now remove wordpress from RewriteRule . wordpress/index.php [L], or resave the permalink in setting.

Comment: Done and done but site unfortunately still not working correctly. Can't open https://www.gas-spring.com/ and https://www.gas-spring.com/wordpress/ is also full or errors. In test environment everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am checking links/permalinks etc... and when I edit a page and update/preview it I see the following message, "Updating failed. Error message: The response is not a valid JSON response."

I did not see this message / error before. Does it have something to do with the site not viewing properly ?

[image]